# How to process and insert millions of MongoDB records into Postgres using Talend Open Studio

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, bigdata, talend

I need to process millions of records coming from MongoDb and put a ETL pipeline to insert that data into a PostgreSQL database. However, in all the methods I've tried, I keep getting the out memory heap space exception. Here's what I've already tried -

1. Tried connecting to MongoDB using tMongoDBInput and put a tMap to process the records and output them using a connection to PostgreSQL. tMap could not handle it.
2. Tried to load the data into a JSON file and then read from the file to PostgreSQL. Data got loaded into JSON file but from there on got the same memory exception.
3. Tried increasing the RAM for the job in the settings and tried the above two methods again, still no change.

I specifically wanted to know if there's any way to stream this data or process it in batches to counter the memory issue.

Also, I know that there are some components dealing with BulkDataLoad. Could anyone please confirm whether it would be helpful here since I want to process the records before inserting and if yes, point me to the right kind of documentation to get that set up.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using the tPostgresqlOutputBulk and tPostgresqlBulkExec components

Comment: Thanks NickW, I tried those but the output file that I have from MongoDb is a JSON file and I could not find a way to use that with tPostgresqlBulkExec. Could go with a CSV but wanted to know if it might work with JSON.

Answer (score 0):

As you already tried all the possibilities the only way that I can see to do this requirement is breaking done the job into multiple sub-jobs or going with incremental load based on key columns or date columns, Considering this as a one-time activity for now.
Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks @vikram kumar. Could you provide some examples of incremental load, I think that it would fit my scenario. No its not a one-time activity but would be on-going for some time.